# Hanging indent within a TOC entry with titletoc?

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, titletoc

Is there a way to add horizontal space to the second and subsequent lines of every TOC entry with titletoc, whether the entry's title wraps to the second line (as in the first section below) or whether the title has a manual line break (as in the second section)? In this example, the space would be before "QUAE" and "EX".

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{CONTEXTUS ORATIONIS ALIQUOT ALCUINI OPERUM QUAE EXIMIA SELECTA SUNT}
    Some text
    \section{SUPPLEMENTUM B:\\ EX ALCUINI EPISTULA AD CAROLUM MAGNUM}
    Some text
\end{document}
```

[image: titletoc TOC hang indent]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you have in mind the `above-code` part of the `\titlecontents` command? You could use `\hangindent1em`, for example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}
% According to the manual, this approximates the settings for \section 
% in the book class ... except for the "\hangindent1em"
\titlecontents{section}
[3.8em] % ie, 1.5em (chapter) + 2.3em
{\hangindent1em}
{\contentslabel{2.3em}}
{\hspace*{-2.3em}}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{CONTEXTUS ORATIONIS ALIQUOT ALCUINI OPERUM QUAE EXIMIA SELECTA SUNT}
    Some text
    \section{SUPPLEMENTUM B:\\ EX ALCUINI EPISTULA AD CAROLUM MAGNUM}
    Some text

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
    \section{SUPPLEMENTUM B:\\ EX BEZOS DOCUMENTO AD LECTOREM CANDIDUM ET BENEVOLUM}
    Some text

\end{document}
```